# How can I display data from API weather?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, display, openweathermap

I have tried to display data from API weather in my code. The problem is I don't know how to start. In this case do I need use `useEffect`? Or maybe event handlers?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Town, Forecast } from "./type";

const WEATHER_API_KEY = "API KEY HERE";

export default function SearchCity(): JSX.Element {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  const [town, setTown] = useState<Town | null>(null);
  const [scores, setScores] = useState<Town[]>([]);

  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!town) return;
    getWeather(town);
    setSearch("");
    setScores([]);
  };

  const getLocations = async (value: string): Promise<Town[]> => {
    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${value}&limit=3&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  };

  const onInputChange = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setSearch(value);
    if (!value) return;
    const locations = await getLocations(value);
    setScores(locations);
  };

  const getWeather = async (town: Town): Promise<Forecast> => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${town.lat}&lon=${town.lon}&units=metric&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  };

  const onScoreSelect = (score: Town) => {
    setTown(score);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (town) {
      setSearch(town.name);
      setScores([]);
    }
  }, [town]);

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          className="input"
          value={search}
          onChange={onInputChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Choose a city"
        ></input>
        <button className="submit" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
        <ul className="list">
          {scores.map((score: Town, index: number) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <button
                className="score-btn"
                onClick={() => onScoreSelect(score)}
              >
                {score.name}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </form>
  );
}
```

I have tried solve my problem on the Internet but I couldn't find the answer (I learn coding, I don't have much experience).

Comment: You can start by some `console.log(res.json());`. Try to do it without react, in pure javascript. It's confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an HTTP request to the API to fetch the data and then update your user interface (UI) with the retrieved data. You can use React and its 'useEffect' hook for this purpose, as well as event handlers if needed.
First, Set Up Your React Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function WeatherApp() {
const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
// Fetch weather data here
}, []); // Empty dependency array to run the effect only once

return (
<div>
  {/* Display weather data here */}
</div>
);
}
export default WeatherApp;
```

-then, Use useEffect for Data Fetching:

```
useEffect(() => {
// Replace with the actual API endpoint and API key
const apiUrl = 'https://api.anyweather.com/weather';
const apiKey = 'your-api-key';
```

-finally:

```
return (
  <div>
    {weatherData ? (
      <div>
        <h1>Weather in {weatherData.location}</h1>
        <p>Temperature: {weatherData.temperature}°C</p>
        <p>Condition: {weatherData.condition}</p>
        {/* Other weather information */}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>Loading weather data...</p>
    )}
  </div>
);

fetch(`${apiUrl}?apikey=${apiKey}`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  setWeatherData(data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error fetching weather data:', error);
});
}, []);
```